# Calculate Geometry function returns underestimated distances

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, distance

I'm making a map of the Colorado Trail and obtained a set of waypoints taken down the entire trail. I projected the set of waypoints from WGS84 (unprojected) to NAD 83 UTM13N after adding to the data frame which is also in the latter projection). Coordinates display as  northing/easting meters as expected. Everything looks fine but using Calculate Geometry to compute trail length (total and individual section lengths) returns erroneous underestimates of published lengths (the published lengths have been measured with a distance wheel). Not even close-- off by nearly 100 miles for the whole trail.

I computed surface length using a 1/3 arc sec DEM but this in no way accounts for the error. I can't figure this out but I feel it has something to do with the projection and how it relates to the initially unprojected waypoints.

Can anyone clear this up as I am out of ideas?

Comment: How close is one waypoint from another?

Comment: This sounds like a [How Long is the Coast of Britain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Long_Is_the_Coast_of_Britain%3F_Statistical_Self-Similarity_and_Fractional_Dimension) problem. Them switchbacks will get you in the end.

Comment: each waypoint is about 1/2 mile apart

Comment: each waypoint is about 1/2 mile apart--  1140 waypoint over 479 miles (true distance)

Comment: Too far by at least two orders of magnitude, possibly three, to compare with a distance wheel.

Comment: ok so this is just a mismatch in resolution? wow-- guess I wouldn't have figured that as the cause. Thanks for the perspective!

Comment: I've been hiking in the Canadian Rockies, and a half-mile interval there could show a simple vertical climb (a la Appalachian Trail), without the 1/4 mile switchbacks to gain that vertical.

Comment: check out arc map's "add z information"; if the issues is related to the movement on the z axis perhaps that tool could help come up with a better measurement (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/add-z-information.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm a GIS newbie and I haven't really learned about that issue concerning resolution surveying.

Comment: @Vince I think your comments could be fused into an answer.

Comment: You have two major issues involving the "switchbacks" problem.  First, your waypoint trail doesn't match the actual trail's meanderings side to side.  Second your DEM resolution is rather rough so it misses the ups and downs the wheel gets.  If you are ambitious you might find good enough aerial imagery to fine tune parts of your trail above treeline.  Then you might find 1m LiDAR based DEM hillshades to better locate the trail under canopy.  Densify it.  Then use the LiDAR DEM to compute 3D distances via the Add Surface Information tool with different sampling distances.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince:

> This sounds like a [How Long is the Coast of
>   Britain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Long_Is_the_Coast_of_Britain%3F_Statistical_Self-Similarity_and_Fractional_Dimension)
>   problem. Them switchbacks will get you in the end.